# What is the limit distribution of $n \min \left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}\right)$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$?

Tags: proof-verification, probability-distributions

I'm solving Questions (c) and (d) in this exercise.

> [image]

In my attempt below, I found that the distribution of $n Y_n$ does not depend on $n$. This makes me suspect I did something wrong.

Could you please verify if my solution is fine or contains logical mistakes?

---

**My attempt:**

c. For $x>0$, we have

$F_{Y_n} (x) = \mathbb P ( Y_n \le x ) = 1-  \mathbb P ( Y_n > x) = 1-  \mathbb P ( X_1 > x )^n = 1 - \left ( \int_x^{+\infty} f(t) \, dt\right )^n =$ $1 - \left ( \int_x^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\theta} \exp (-\frac{t}{\theta}) \, dt\right )^n = 1 - (\exp (-\frac{x}{\theta}))^n = 1- \exp (-\frac{nx}{\theta})$

d.  For $x>0$, we have

$F_{nY_n} (x) = \mathbb P ( n Y_n \le x ) = \mathbb P ( Y_n \le \frac{x}{n} ) = F_{Y_n} (\frac{x}{n}) = 1- \exp (-\frac{nx}{n\theta}) = 1- \exp (-\frac{x}{\theta})$. Thus the distribution of $n Y_n$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: I can't spot any flaws.

Comment: It is well-known that $\min(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ has exponential distribution if the $X_i$ have exponential distribution and are independent. This with parameter $\lambda_1+\cdots\lambda_n$ if $X_i$ has parameter $\lambda_i$. So c) is fine. Also d) is fine. If $Z$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ then $cZ$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda/c$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification!